# Is it possible to chain several Discord modals? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My goal is to chain or link several different discord modals after one-another in order to create a continuous form since Discord does not allow to add more than 5 items or "questions" per modal.

The goal is to have modal_1 and modal_2 with 5 questions in each. Every time a command is ran by a user, modal_1 would be displayed. After completion, the user would submit modal_1, after which modal_2 would appear.

Sadly, all my tries were unsuccessful, with Discord not closing the first modal after submitting it and instead returning the error: "Something went wrong, try again". This error is not a code error, but inside of the Discord modal.

Here is a code snippet to illustrate what I am doing:

```
class Modal_2(discord.ui.Modal,title="Modal_2"):
    question_1 = discord.ui.TextInput(label="That's the second question")

    asnyc def on_sumbit(self,interaction:discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Thanks for your input")

class Modal_1(discord.ui.Modal,title="Modal_1"):
    question_1 = discord.ui.TextInput(label="That's the first question")

    asnyc def on_sumbit(self,interaction:discord.Interaction):
         await interaction.response.send_modal(Modal_2())

class main(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
          self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name="survey")
    async def main(self,interaction:discord.Interaction)
         await interaction.response.send_modal(Modal_1())
```

After the command is run, shows the first modal. Though when submitted, the second modal never shows up nor is the first modal dismissed. It only returns  the error: "Something went wrong, try again" within the first modal after submitting it, but now actual "code" error or exception is shown in the console.

Comment: Well, you have to implement a proper listener for all the Modals and then probably edit the original message every time someone interacted with the Modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Looking [in this section of Discord's Developers' Portal](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#responding-to-an-interaction), you can read that MODAL can't be the callback of a MODAL_SUBMIT interaction.

Depending on what the data is, I would either use a form webpage or try to do something with the View Widgets, especially [TextInputs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#id3), since you can send as many messages with these as you want.